# Spark - WARN HDFSBackedStateStoreProvider: The state for version 1 doesn't exist in loadedMaps

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hdfs

I am currently working on a Spark Structured Streaming job and it seems that on every batch interval I get the warning:

`WARN HDFSBackedStateStoreProvider: The state for version N doesn't exist in loadedMaps.  Reading snapshot file and delta files if needed...Note that this is normal for the first batch of starting query.` - Where N is being incremented on each batch.

I am seeing this flooded in the logs in both local mode (where checkpointing is disabled) and when running on YARN (EMR).

Question is: Can this be safely ignored? Turning on debug logging HDFSBackedStateStoreProvider indicates that there is time being spent reading the snapshot and delta files, so I have some concern.

Here is my seemingly minimal SparkConf

```scala
val sparkConf: SparkConf = {
      val conf = new SparkConf()
        .setAppName("Structured Streaming")
        .set("spark.sql.autoBroadcastJoinThreshold", "-1")
        .set("spark.speculation", "false")

      if (App.isLocal)
        conf
          .set("spark.cassandra.output.consistency.level", "LOCAL_ONE")
          .setMaster("local[*]")
      else
        conf
          .set("spark.cassandra.connection.host", PropertyLoader.getProperty("cassandra.contactPoints"))
          .set("spark.cassandra.connection.local_dc", PropertyLoader.getProperty("cassandra.localDC"))
          .set("spark.cassandra.connection.ssl.enabled", "true")
          .set("spark.cassandra.connection.ssl.trustStore.path", PropertyLoader.truststorePath)
          .set("spark.cassandra.connection.ssl.trustStore.password", PropertyLoader.getProperty("cassandra.truststorePassword"))
          .set("spark.cassandra.auth.username", PropertyLoader.getProperty("cassandra.username"))
          .set("spark.cassandra.auth.password", PropertyLoader.getProperty("cassandra.password"))
          .set("spark.executor.logs.rolling.maxRetainedFiles", "20")
          .set("spark.executor.logs.rolling.maxSize", "524288000")
          .set("spark.executor.logs.rolling.strategy", "size")
          .set("spark.cleaner.referenceTracking.cleanCheckpoints", "true")
          .set("spark.sql.streaming.metricsEnabled", "true")
          .setJars(Array[String](SparkContext.jarOfClass(getClass).get))
```

Comment: could you please provide more details of the code you are using? I get a similar error with foreachBatch operation in update mode to Delta Lake. In the code above I see only `sparkConf`

Comment: It would take me a while to actually dig up the code related to this warning. But yes, I was using foreachBatch in update mode IIRC.

Comment: Hi, were you able to solve this issue ? I am also getting same warnings